# How to randomly generate email address on postman request using pre-request script

Tags: api-testing

I am new with Postman > Pre-request Script, Can you help me create a random email value for my API Request. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to Pre-request Script, I would suggest using another efficient way to generate a random email:
like **qa{{$timestamp}}@gmail.com**. Here, **{{$timestamp}}** will always give you a unique number that never occurred in the past.

[image]

Moreover, if you want to stick with the Pre-request Script, then here is the way to do so:

[image: Set the random email in the environment so that you can use it in the request.]

Now, access the environment variable in the request as:

[image: You might face 'Unexpected token error in JSON, that can be fixed by putting environment variable in double-quotes.]

Comment: Hi the pre-requisite code doesn't work. pm.environment.set('a',_.$randomEmail) , now try accessing a

Comment: I add in Pre-request Script as:  **pm.environment.set("randomAge", parseInt(_.random(20, 80)));** and in body request, get randomAge as: **{
  "firstName": "{{$randomFirstName}}",
  "lastName": "{{$randomLastName}}",
  "age": {{randomAge}}
}**

Comment: And above script worked for me.

Comment: Hi Ghulam , the script you mentioned in comment is entirely different from the answer.  The approach in the new script is just a normal operation. It is not using the dynamic variable of postman.  My question was about your code of using dynamic variable in postman scripts.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use below code in your pre-requist script**

```
 const uuid = require('uuid')
 let email=uuid()+'@domain.com'
 pm.environment.set('email',email)
```

**and access the same using**

1. {{email}}  , in non script locations
2. `pm.environment.get('email')` in test scripts

**You can also use other unique identifier libraries given below, instead of uuid**

```
 const moment = require('moment')
 let email=moment().valueOf()+'@domain.com'
 pm.environment.set('email',email)
```

Or

```
 let email=_.random(1000)+'@domain.com'
 pm.environment.set('email',email)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am currently on Postman v7.29.1. It appears that `$randomEmail` (one of many `$random` vars) is a built-in variable. So you are free to skip the pre-request script.

```
// req body - raw/json

{
  "firstName": "{{$randomFirstName}}",
  "lastName": "{{$randomLastName}}",
  "email": "{{$randomEmail}}",
  "phone": "{{$randomPhoneNumber}}",
}
```

*Note:* The double-quotations `"` around the curly braces `{{ }}` are important, as are the prefixed dollar signs `$` in the variable names.

Comment: Interesting. There's a reference to the official documentation: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/#domains-emails-and-usernames

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate a UUID and append it to a domain.

```
const uuid = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
        Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
const email = "user_" + uuid + "@myDomain.com";
pm.environment.set("currentEmail", email);
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403498/2252076

Then, you can reference the `{{currentEmail}}` variable anywhere on the request or on the tests.

Answer (score 1):

use postman Dynamic variables as "{{$postmanDynamicVariables}}" in pre-request Script

Example

```
const email = "{{$randomEmail}}";

pm.environment.set("email", email);

// or to generate and set random full name

pm.environment.set("name","{{$randomFullName}}");
```